# Closing an alert box from another class in android studio(java)

Tags: java, bluetooth, alert

I have two classes, one that will be having a function that will make an alert box pop up, and the other class will be reading revived strings via bluetooth from the inputstream, and if the received string was equal to "TQ" i want to close the alert on all the devices that received the "TQ", here's my code

BluetoothConnectionService:

```
  public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                if (incomingMessage == "TQ"){


                }
                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                Intent  incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                  incomingMessageIntent.putExtra ("theMessage", incomingMessage );
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Main2Activity:

```
private  void alert(){
    //********sends a string via bluetooth*********\\
    byte[] bytes = "TQ".toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);

        AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       helpBuilder.setTitle("Trivial Question");
        helpBuilder.setMessage("xxxxxx");
     helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int, which) {
    }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to make the AlertDialog a global public variable in Main2Activity, then just dismiss it from the connection service.

```
public AlertDialog mDialog;
```

Change your alert method to this:

```
private  void alert(){
    //********sends a string via bluetooth*********\\
    byte[] bytes = "TQ".toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);

    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Trivial Question");
    helpBuilder.setMessage("xxxxxx");
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int, which) {
    }
        ); 
    mDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    mDialog.show();
}
```

Create a new method in Main2Activity to dismiss the dialog:

```
public void dismissAlertDialog(){
    if(mDialog != null){
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then call dismissAlertDialog() if the code is found:

```
public void run(){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        // Read from the InputStream
        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            if (incomingMessage == "TQ"){

                ((Main2Activity)mContext).dismissAlertDialog();

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
            Intent  incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
              incomingMessageIntent.putExtra ("theMessage", incomingMessage );
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need to pass the context into the BluetoothConnectionService class constructor and assign it to **mContext**.